# Is there an "article searcher" for a certain list of words?

Tags: vocabulary, resources, online-resources

If I want to practice some new English words, and I need to understand them in a better way- to read them in various articles, is there a tool for that?

For a set of very few words, search engines could manage that. However, if there are 20-30 words or more, basically what I can absorb in a day, I haven't find such a tool.

So far there are some AI-driven tools that can generate articles based on some settings, but I think human-written articles help me better, especially from the media and literature.

It would be great if there's such a tool. Imagine if I can make a search request based on my “new words vocabulary", then it returns article sections from different sources, while they include those words I need to memorize.

To be more specific, take this as an example:
1) I do a vocabulary test, to determine words that I know;
2) I pull a list from new words, say a list includes 40 words, then send a request;
3) It returns 2 sections from news, 1 section from a book. All the paragraphs contains mostly the words I know and the words from the list I pulled. Which means, it doesn't introduce too many new words that makes it too hard to read them.

In general I can verify what I know (step 1) and practice (step 2 and 3) regularly.

Comment: You may find this helpful: http://www.freecollocation.com/

Comment: Either (i) enter a word or phrase in a good search engine, or (ii) use the examples given in books from the results of Google Ngram Viewer: https://books.google.com/ngrams

Comment: @user121863 - That site doesn't work.

Comment: Hint:  If you want to use Google to search for "red potato", enter `"red potato"` (with quotes) on the input line.  Adding the quotes tells Google you're searching for that specific string, not just those two words.